# How to create a TypeScript rule based on a presence of a character?

Tags: typescript

The context is [this change](https://github.com/gajus/roarr/commit/a7376a9be6f25d05ea8dd194eae2e112c838ab56) in Roarr logger.

In short, it says that if the function's first parameter is a `string` and the function has multiple parameters, then the first string must contain `%` – otherwise, it is an improper invocation, e.g.

```
const log = <T extends string>(message: T, ...args: number[]) => {};

// valid
log('foo');
log('foo %d', 1);

// invalid
log('foo', 1);
```

I've seen TypeScript tokenize strings – is it possible to detect if a string literal contains `%` character?

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your use cases when pasted into a standalone IDE.  You can write `type HasPercent = \`${string}%${string}\`` but I don't know if that behaves the way you want without examples of use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Using hint from @jcalz I figured out that I am looking for:

```
type Foo<T extends string> = T extends `${string}%${string}` ? 'FOO' : 'BAR';

type A = Foo<'foo'>; // = 'BAR'
type B = Foo<'foo%bar'>; // 'FOO'
```

My specific case then becomes:

```
const log = <T extends string>(message: T, ...args: Array<T extends `${string}%${string}` ? number : never>) => {};

// valid
log('foo');
log('foo %d', 1);

// invalid
log('foo', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this:

```
type FormatterMap = {
  "s": string
  "t": boolean
  "d": number
}

type MessageToArgs<M extends string> = 
  M extends `${string}${"%"}${infer V}${infer R}`
    ? V extends keyof FormatterMap
      ? [FormatterMap[V], ...MessageToArgs<R>]
      : [...MessageToArgs<R>]
    : []

const log = <T extends string>(message: T, ...args: MessageToArgs<T>) => {};
```

We can use a recursive type to build a *tuple* of arguments based on the provided string. This will make sure that the right amount of arguments is provided and that the type of each argument must be correct.

```
log("a")                              // ok
log("%s")                             // Error: string argument is missing
log("%s", "a")                        // ok
log("%s %d", "a")                     // Error: number argument is missing
log("%s %d", "a", 0)                  // ok
log("%s %d %t", "a", 0, "not bool")   // Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'
log("%s %d %t", "a", 0, true)         // ok
```

This could be overkill depending on your actual use-case though...

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLYENjAggsisUC8UA3gLABQUUARAM5UBcUNwCAlgHYDm5lVwDUAEZw4AGwgp2PagBMB7AK5JBmcgF9y5UJChYINGik4QAKnACCCTjQA8WKBAAeGdjJpMWHTgD4CUafZOLm5QAAYAJETMbFxqkVQApFRxRBwAZphQAGop6ZkASmqh0pQA-NkOzhCu7gDWECBwabCIqOiYOGAllFDlANrwyGgY2Lh9WQC6ADRQAHTzegZGphZWtvneE92UjH3zs4uGxmaW1jYbWxQ9u5eaZOQAxnDszFCicJx%20NiaVwe7RXm8AAokPojhBGCYZvsUGtGIdlic1t9vABKAi%20IhqADcd3enCBVBQVHRPTJ5IplIA9FSoHBauR8YSUFAEnRSZTORSaVAAKIIBCIRgArhQWGcJTVYBQVjuJCymheRkfZmsugzIkkrlcnn05UEolq1lyDXEjnayg8-mChCMRTKTLiyXsaWyqDygxKshMw1s41UU0BqAABnNnN1DO9Kt97gSMlZ-EDM2DMxYCggHIjQA)